# Email address wraped with a cancel mark or button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When you are inserting an email in gmail or yahoo in TO: text area of the sending form and its correct. You notice that email address is wrapped or folded in a 'fluid like transparent thing' with a cancel button or 'X' mark at the end. When you click the 'X' mark, that email is automatically removed from the sending email form. Can someone explain how the email is wrapped with that fluid because I would like to wrap option selected from a form drop down menu using such 'a fluid like thing with an X mark so that when the user clicks the X mark, the option is automatically deleted from the list of the selections

Comment: The same functionality applies here when you tag your question for example. This is achieved using javascript, but the question is too broad for SO. You should try implementing this and come back if you're having a coding problem.

Comment: You can inspect on your own, via your browser devtools. Still, you may want to hear about [this kind of plugins](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), that add such feature to basic `<select>` tags.

Comment: Guys are being too harsh. This is not such a bad question with a simple specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like the Chosen Plugin: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ ?
Take a look at the "Multiple Select"-section.

If you download and include the plugin you can start with this little piece of code: `$("#mymultipleselect").chosen();`

Make shure you have set the "multiple" attribute in your select: 
    `<select multiple>...</select>`

Comment: much better!  Good summary.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Chosen jQuery/Prototype plugin, specifically the Selected and Disabled Support example

[image]

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/